# thorntail dependency is pulling a dependency which I have excluded

Tags: maven, build, pom.xml, thorntail, blackduck

There's a dependency called jsoup version 1.8.3 which is getting bundled in my jar but it doesn't shows up when i run mvn dependency:tree command. Below is my POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.product</groupId>
        <artifactId>product</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.40.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>product-collector</artifactId>
    <name>product-collector</name>
    <description>Factory Automation Collector for Manufacturer</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <version.thorntail>2.7.0.Final</version.thorntail>
        <collector-installer-path>/opt/company/Collector/Installer/</collector-installer-path>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${version.thorntail}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>management</artifactId>
            <version>${version.thorntail}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
            <version>${version.thorntail}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-authz-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${version.resteasy}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${version.resteasy}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/json-schema-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/json-schema-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>collector</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
                <artifactId>thorntail-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.thorntail}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources-productInstaller</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/collectorInstallerArchive</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>../product-core-parent/product-webservice/src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>config.properties</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>./src/main/resources/installer/</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>../product-installer/src/main/productInstallerArchive</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>dockerpull_aws.sh</include>
                                        <include>dockerpull_nexus.sh</include>
                                        <include>dockercleanup.sh</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-scripts</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <chmod file="target/collectorInstallerArchive/*.sh"
                                    perm="755" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.hazendaz.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>makeself-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.beta6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveDir>collectorInstallerArchive/</archiveDir>
                    <fileName>collector-installer.bin</fileName>
                    <label>Distro Self Extraction</label>
                    <startupScript>./collector-installer.sh</startupScript>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>makeself</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>makeself</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>collectorDocker</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.28.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <images>
                                <image>
                                    <name>product-collector</name>
                                    <build>
                                        <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</dockerFileDir>
                                        <assembly>
                                            <inline>
                                                <files>
                                                    <file>
                                                        <source>./target/collector-thorntail.jar</source>
                                                        <outputDirectory>${collector-installer-path}</outputDirectory>
                                                    </file>
                                                    <file>
                                                        <source>../product-core-parent/product-webservice/src/main/resources/config.properties</source>
                                                        <outputDirectory>${collector-installer-path}</outputDirectory>
                                                    </file>
                                                </files>
                                            </inline>
                                        </assembly>
                                    </build>
                                </image>
                            </images>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

When dependency tree didn't help, i started excluding dependencies one by one to check which dependency is bringing jsoup. So, I found that ejb artifact of io.thorntail dependency is bringing it.
I then tried excluding jsoup from ejb dependency by using exclusion tag

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
    <version>${version.thorntail}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

but it was still coming in collector-thorntail.jar in target folder at this path: product-collector/target/collector-thorntail.jar/m2Repo/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.8.3/jsoup-1.8.3.jar

How do i exclude this jsoup dependency from my project as it is showing vulnerability in blackduck scan?

I tried excluding it using exclusion tag of POM.xml but it is still being bundled under the jar.

Comment: May it be that the problematic JAR is part of another JAR, i.e. packaged into another JAR?

Comment: Since you're trying to exclude a dependency that is flagged as vulnerable, I feel compelled to warn you that Thorntail itself is end of life for more that 3 years (see https://thorntail.io/posts/the-end-of-an-era/) and I'm 100% sure many other components are also vulnerable. You should make every effort to migrate off of Thorntail as soon as possible. Quarkus and WildFly are both great options to consider.